# Filtering an ICollectionView on Multiple CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I currently have a list of 27,000 Companies that all fit into at least 1 of 3 categories, `Subcontractors`, `Suppliers` and `Planthire`. All of these companies are loaded into an `ICollectionView`, which is the `ItemsSource` for a `DataGrid`.

what I've previously been able to do in the past is filter the `ICollectionView` based on one property of a `Model`. For example if I had a list of jobs, and all jobs had an `ITName` property attached, I could do something like this;

```
private void OnCheckBoxCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkedEmployees = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (CheckBox checkBox in _employees.Children)
    {
        if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            checkedEmployees.Add((string)checkBox.Content);
            checkedEmployees.Add((string)checkBox.Tag);
        }
    }

    JobsCollectionView.Filter =
        job => checkedEmployees.Contains((job as JobModel).ITName);        
}
```

**The Problem Now**

The problem now is that I am trying to filter on multiple properties of a `CompanyModel`. With irrelevant parts taken out of it it looks like this;

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public int Subcontractor { get; set; }
    public int Supplier { get; set; }
    public int Planthire { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is if the `Subcontractor` `CheckBox` is checked but the others aren't, only show `Subcontractors`. If the `Subcontractor` and `Supplier` `CheckBoxes` are both checked, show `Companies` that fit into the `Subcontractor` AND `Supplier` categories. This is what I have attempted so far, however it does not achieve this;

```
private void FilterCompanyType(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkedCompanyFilters = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (CheckBox checkBox in companyTypes.Children)
    {
        if (checkBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            checkedCompanyFilters.Add((string)checkBox.Tag);
        }
    }

    if (subbieCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CompanyICollectionView.Filter =
            company => checkedCompanyFilters.Contains((company as CompanyModel).Subcontractor.ToString());
    }

    if (supplierCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CompanyICollectionView.Filter =
                company => checkedCompanyFilters.Contains((company as CompanyModel).Supplier.ToString());
    }

    if (planthireCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CompanyICollectionView.Filter =
            company => checkedCompanyFilters.Contains((company as CompanyModel).Planthire.ToString());
    }          
}
```

How can I modify this method so that it achieves what I would like it to?

Answer (score 1):

Your company model should be changed to use an `enum` for the type of company and a single `int` for the key.  The `enum` should be declared with the `[Flags]` attribute so that it can be used for Boolean operations.  Then your filters look like this:

```
CompanyICollectionView.Filter =
    company => checkedCompanyFilters.Where(
        ((company as CompanyModel).CompanyType & CompanyTypes.Whatever) 
            == CompanyTypes.Whatever).Key.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple filter conditions:

```
var isSubbie = subbieCheckBox.IsChecked == true;
var isSupplier = supplierCheckBox.IsChecked == true;
...

CompanyICollectionView.Filter = company =>
{
    var model = (CompanyModel)company;
    return isSubbie && checkedCompanyFilters.Contains(model.Subcontractor.ToString()) ||
        isSupplier && checkedCompanyFilters.Contains(model.Supplier.ToString()) ||
        ...
};
```

---

I thought what `checkedCompanyFilters` is a set of different subcontractors but it looks like you want to filter by just one. Then simply change above return line to something like this (I am not sure how do you define *company is subcontractor*, is it when `Subcontractor > 0` ?):

```
    return isSubbie && model.Subcontractor > 0 ||
        isSupplier && model.Supplier > 0 ||
        ...
```

---

> I would still like `Subcontractors` that are also `Suppliers`, i.e. `model.Subcontractor > 0 && model.Suppliers > 0` if `isSubbie && isSupplier`

Then simply replace `return` with either:

```
    return (isSubbie ? model.Subcontractor > 0 : model.Subcontractor == 0) &&
        (isSupplier ? model.Supplier > 0 : model.Supplier == 0) &&
        ...
```

or:

```
    return (isSubbie && model.Subcontractor > 0 || !isSubbie && model.Subcontractor == 0) &&
        (isSupplier && model.Supplier > 0 || !isSupplier && model.Supplier == 0) &&
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting: `Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool'`

Comment: This is working better than the original, however now the Companies are just adding on. So all `Subcontractors` and `Suppliers` are now being displayed, however I would like Companies that are BOTH `Subcontractors` AND `Suppliers`.

Comment: See edit, how do you define *company is subcontractor*?.

Comment: If `model.Subcontractor == 1` then they are a subcontractor, if 0 then they are not. `CheckedCompanyFilters` is three `Checkboxes`, one is Subcontractors, one Suppliers and one is Planthire.

Comment: You don't need `CheckedCompanyFilters`. Last edit should work, `Filter` will store lambda with captures values of checkboxes, therefore you don't need additional set to store it.

Comment: It's getting closer, however it still is just adding one onto the other. It's listing all `Subcontractors` and all `Suppliers`. I would still like `Subcontractors` that are also `Suppliers`, i.e. `model.Subcontractor > 0 && model.Suppliers > 0` if `isSubbie && isSupplier`